# python: How can I remove lambda in this code?

Tags: python, tkinter, lambda

Im new at programming and have no clue how to use lambda in programming. Im asking if there is a way to edit this code so that I dont need to use lambda on it.

```
from tkinter import *
def define(a):
    pass

root = Tk()

#this line
auto = Button(root, text="auto", command=lambda: define(True)).pack()
```

Comment: I don't think this programming is running either way because the `define` function isn't taking any arguments although one is given as `define(True)`

Comment: create a function that doesn't take any parameter then use `command=somFun` now call  other functions from `someFun` or you can also use  [`functools.partial`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.partial)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to remove `lambda` from your code you must define a function return another function `define`.

That is,

```
def replacement():
    return define(argument)
```

This way you don't have to use lambda in calling `Button`. Instead you would call `Button` as :

```
auto = Button(root, text="auto", command=replacement).pack()
```

I hope this helps. But, you should learn what lambda's are.

Comment: This will execute the function even before the button is pressed.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out. I have edited. Please have a look again.

Comment: `return define(argument)` should be `return define(True)` because `argument` is undefined.

Answer (score 2):

You can also use `partial` from `functools`. It is basically the same as what @Suraj Upadhyay suggested.
This is the code:

```py
from tkinter import *
from functools import partial

def define(a):
    pass

root = Tk()

function = partial(define, True) # The first arg is the function name and the rest are the function args
auto = Button(root, text="auto", command=function)
auto.pack()
```

Comment: you could just use `command=partial(define, True)`